# Installing EVGA Hybrid 3090 ti

Tags: gpu

I recently bought an EVGA FTW3 Hybrid 3090ti and found that the air cooler should be attached at the top of my PC case.

[Upper part is the cooler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8NyH7.jpg)

Unfortunately, my PC has a huge CPU cooler as you can see from the attached photo. There would be no way to put my graphics card’s cooler besides it.

[CPU cooler 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dbLWS.jpg)
[CPU cooler 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gtcB8.jpg)

What are the options left for me? Should I detach CPU cooler and hope this huge ceiling fan also does the job for it?

I’m looking forward to getting some valuable feedback. Thank you in advance.

Comment: At an absolute minimum you will have to remove the CPU cooler to fit the GPU cooler in the top of the case. As the GPU cooler is an AIO (All In One) unit you are unlikely to be able to disconnect it from the GPU to create a loop for both the CPU and GPU. Your options are to 1) get a smaller CPU cooler 2) get a full-loop water cooling system for the CPU/GPU, or 3) get a GPU without water cooling.

Comment: @Mokubai Thank you so much for your advice!! What should I consider when I buy a smaller CPU cooler? Does it depend on CPU's generation, TDP, or manufacturer?

Comment: it depends on all those things. You have to buy one that is compatible with your CPU socket so that it comes with the right fixing hardware to fit your motherboard. You also need to know the TDP of your CPU so that you get a cooler that can actually dissipate all the heat the CPU can generate. If you have an Intel CPU  then typing your CPU into Google ([example](https://www.google.com/search?q=i7-8700k)) will get you an [Intel ARK page](https://www.intel.co.uk/content/www/uk/en/products/sku/126684) that tells you your TDP (95W) and Socket (FCLGA1151 or just 1151 for short).

Comment: @Mokubai Wow! I appreciate your detailed comment. It helped me a lot. Seems like mine is a quite old one (i7-6700) as I bought my PC 8 years ago. :D Then I'll head to buy a new CPU cooler. Thank you very much!